# MongoDB find $in sorting issue

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to get docs from MongoDB collection where ID's are in array:

```
[
  '5f80a44d0179262f7c2e6a42',
  '5f8c00762fae890e9c4d029c',
  '5f802cf8abac1116a46bf9d4'
]
```

The issue is, docs are not coming in sequence of my array ID's. They are coming (1, 0, 2) for above array ID's.

How can I make them in sequence of my ID's array? I am using, NodeJs + Mongoose.

My code:

```
var ids = ['5f80a44d0179262f7c2e6a42','5f8c00762fae890e9c4d029c','5f802cf8abac1116a46bf9d4']

Product.find({
  _id: {
    $in: ids
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible with `find()`, or any functionality available in MongoDB related to this,

It is possible with `aggregate()` but this will just fulfil your expected result,

I am not recommending to use this because this will affect performance of query response, this could be a heavy transaction.

- `$match` your conditions
- `$group` by null and make array of all matching objects in `root`
- `$addFields` to add ids array that we search for
- `$unwind` deconstruct ids array, this will deconstruct in sequence as per we provided in ids array
- `$project`, `$reduce` input as root array and check condition if id match then return object
- `$replaceWith` to replace root object to root

```
var ids = [
  ObjectId("5f802cf8abac1116a46bf9d4"), 
  ObjectId("5f8c00762fae890e9c4d029c"), 
  ObjectId("5f80a44d0179262f7c2e6a42")
];

Product.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: { $in: ids } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { ids: ids } },
  { $unwind: "$ids" },
  {
    $project: {
      root: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$root",
          initialValue: {},
          in: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this._id", "$ids"] }, "$$this", "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $replaceWith: "$root" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1PGh9gCdHc0)